# select a "fake" column that is a range of specific numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I need to select table's *a* information along with a range of specific numbers, that is, for every *a.id* I want to show every number in the range, **using PostgreSQL 8.4**.

Let's suppose the range is the numbers 123, 175 and 192, this would be the result I want:

<kbd>range</kbd><kbd>a.id</kbd>
<kbd>123</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>    
<kbd>175</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>    
<kbd>192</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>    
<kbd>123</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>    
<kbd>175</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>    
<kbd>192</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>    
<kbd>123</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>    
<kbd>175</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>    
<kbd>192</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>

I know I can achieve this using

```
select range, a.id
from a
inner join generate_series(1, 100, 1) range on true
```

But the thing is, I don't want to use `generate_series` because my range is random numbers, is there another way to do it?

Maybe something like this:

```
select range, a.id
from a
where range in (123, 175, 192)
group by range, a.id;
```

Comment: I think I understand now.  So you have a table called `a` with an `id` column and you are trying to return ranges with those values?  Which range should go with with value?  That last query has 5 ranges -- if table `a` only has 3 rows, why would 123 go with 1 for example?

Comment: For every `a.id` I want to show every number of the range

Comment: @sgeddes I just realised I had written a wrong example for what I want, I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comment:

> For every a.id I want to show every number of the range

This creates what is called a `cartesian product`.  Here's one generic option using a `cross join` with `union all`:

```
select a.id, r.rng
from a cross join (
  select 123 as rng 
  union all select 234
  union all select 556
  union all select 653
  union all select 634) r
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7927b/2)

Comment: In the example my range is only 3 numbers, but pratically speaking it vary from 3 to a couple thousands, I appreciate your contribution but didn't find it much elegant.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior -- If you have a thousand random numbers, you'll have to write them out somehow.  Using `union all` is just one example.  Since you're using `postrgesql`, a shorter alternative would be to use `values` lists: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html .  You'll still need the cross join, but at least you wouldn't have to write `union all` multiple times....

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior -- see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683429/postgresql-insert-the-cartesian-product-of-two-or-more-sets

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to have a query you can easily use with a list of multiple numbers as parameter. Use an array:

```
with a(id) as (values (1), (2), (3))

select rng, id
from unnest(array[123, 175, 192]) rng
cross join a;

 rng | id 
-----+----
 123 |  1
 175 |  1
 192 |  1
 123 |  2
 175 |  2
 192 |  2
 123 |  3
 175 |  3
 192 |  3
(9 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

[@sgeddes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073631/sgeddes) and [@klin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995738/klin) answers have contributed a lot, even though I have accepted a answer, I'm writing this one to describe 3 solutions that I found to work and are "elegant". Sadly, I don't know which performs better.

```
// This is the one I'm using
select unnest(array[123, 175, 192]), a.id
from a
group by range, a.id

select range, a.id
from a
inner join (values (123), (175), (192)) data(range) on true
group by range, a.id

select range, a.id
from a
inner join unnest(array[123, 175, 192]) range on true
group by range, a.id
```